# c# compare 2 List<string>'s line by line

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 List arrays. 1 is called "friends" the other is "followers". Both arrays contains lots of id numbers. I want to compare the 2 lists line by line and create a new list which holds the items which dont occur on both lists.

Here is the code I have:

```
List<string> notfollowingmelist = new List<string>();

        foreach (string friend in friends)
        {
            bool isfriend = false;
            foreach (string follower in followers)
            {
                if (friend == follower)
                {
                    isfriend = true;
                }
                if (isfriend)
                {
                    isfriend = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    notfollowingmelist.Add(friend);


                }
            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show(notfollowingmelist.Count.ToString());
```

Am I going about this the correct way or is there a better route to the soltuion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> notFollowers = friends.Where(x => !followers.Contains(x));
```

BTW: your code is not correct.

Comment: Careful, this solution may very well be O(n^2).

Comment: @aquinas: Aggree, can anyone confirm this?

Comment: It will certainly be `O(n^2)`: you are looping over followers once for each friend. See the set-operation approach in my answer for a more efficient version.

Answer (score 7):

### LINQ solution

Numbers which appear on **both** lists:

```
friends.Intersect(followers);
```

All numbers that appear in **at least one of the lists**:

```
friends.Union(followers);
```

All numbers that appear in **exactly one** of the lists:

```
var intersectResult = friends.Intersect(followers);
var unionResult = friends.Union(followers);

var exactlyOnce = unionResult.Exclude(intersectResult);
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 4):

Linq is the correct approach, but here's another way to do it:

```
List<string> notFollowingMe = friends.Except(followers).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd sort both lists using something like a quicksort, then step through the two lists together to determine which items are unique.  Sorting should take O(nlogn) time and stepping through the lists should take O(n) time, for an overall time complexity of O(nlogn).  Your current implementation takes O(n^2) time, which is slower.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
friends.qsort()
followers.qsort()
disjointList = new List()
int i=0
int j=0
while(i<friends.size() && j<followers.size()){
    if(friends[i] == followers[j]){
        i++
        j++
    }else if(friends[i] < followers[j]){
        disjointList.add(friends[i])
        i++
    }else{
        disjointList.add(followers[j])  // note: omit this line if you only want a list of friends that are not followers
        j++
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Code not only has to do its job but should be readable to other developers. Trying to figure out what this function does without any context would take exponentially longer than the accepted answer. There are cases where something like this may be required, however this is not one of those cases.

Comment: Highly inefficient solution. Not recommended! But this is a nice demo on how to artificially and uselessly complicate your life.

Answer (score 0):

(In VB.Net) The logic is the same, should work.

```
For Each s As String In friends
    If Not (followers.Contains(s)) Then
        notfollowingmelist.Add(s)
    End If
Next
For Each s As String In followers
    If Not (friends.Contains(s)) Then
        notfollowingmelist.Add(s)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @Brandon, this method is much faster in case the tow lists are large and the speed is a concern. Life itself is complicted, sometimes you get no way to simplify it.

Comment: First of all, how is looping through the lists separately faster than executing a LINQ function on a single list? Second, your logic is faulty. How are you going to loop through a list of followers (people who by definition are following you) and add them to a list of people who are not following you?

Comment: I wanted to say Brandon's method is fast, but I do not know how to put after his solution. My solution is just for reference, I may not understand the question well.

Comment: scott, the logic on my part is fine

Comment: Hi Scott, on Brandon's code, it has no comments and is not readable, kind of :), but the logic is still clear. If you have sorted two lists, and compare both simultaneously in the order, you will be able to find out the common elements.